# Launchd service logs?

Tags: macos, launchd

I need to create a service in macOS Monterey but sudo launchctl start myservice does not work, my app won't start it seems, I don't know why. Where are the logs? In Linux I just use journalctl, but is there any similar thing in macOS?

In the Console app there is nothing related to services in system.log just couple of random lines about ASL Sender Statistics...

Here is my plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>myservice</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Applications/myapp/bin/mybinary</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you add the plist you use? Also, you can set log destinations within the service definition.

Comment: Added the plist file.

Answer (score 10):

Debugging these jobs is much easier with a gui like https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/

Here is [another thread with tips on debugging agents and daemons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217456/5472).

In a nutshell, add keys to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to files you can tail.

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/local.job.err</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/local.job.out</string>
```

Comment: Note: The trial version has some restrictions, but viewing logs of previously-run jobs is not one of those limitations.  So it's a handy tool, even if you never purchase the full/non-trial version.

Comment: on BigSur 11.5.1, once I add these two, error occured: Load failed: 109: Invalid property list, I check the log path and it's mode, not these problems. it's more like these two key doesn't exist in bigsur 11.5.1